# D7 Webform tokens for user fields

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens, users

In D6 we could configure a webform field to pull profile data by using  a token like %profile[key] and assigning the user field to the form [(Details here)](http://drupal.org/node/296453).
How can we to something similar in D7 using the user fields instead of the profile fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this can't be done using the standard webform module. It defines a limited list of tokens that hasn't been updated for the new user fields. They are included as tokens (if you use field_nnn) but they will be an empty value.

After initially looking at building a custom module, it seems that the Tokens module does make user fields available in the form [user:field_nnn].

Comment: Good luck with this then! When do you estimate that it will be ready?

Comment: It's an internal module. But see the update - it may not be necessary :)

Comment: So if you have tokens installed you should be able to user [user:field_full_name] for example? I'm doing this and it is not printing out correctly - my email shows [user:field_full_name]

Answer (score 2):

The new Webform 4.x uses the token system. The ongoing process can be followed [here](http://drupal.org/node/1001798)